# Angular to call different variables dynamically Is it possible?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I have a function to do a series of tasks on a variable, the thing is that I have to do another function that is exactly the same, only the variable on which it acts changes.

The question is to reuse and save code. Could it be possible to send the name of the variable in a string to the function and have it use the corresponding variable according to the string received?

The only way I know is to put both variables in an associative array and pass to the function the name of the corresponding associative key of the array, but I don't think it's "elegant" to create an array just for that and I've never done something like that in any other language either.

A simple example of what I'm trying to do:

componente1.component.ts

```
   accionComun (nombreVariable: string) {
    
      //  I want to print the variable whose name is the name nombreVariable
      alert();
    
   }
   
   accionComun("variable1");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the variable to `this` like so:

```
   accionComun (nombreVariable: string) {
    
      //  I want to print the variable whose name is the name nombreVariable
      alert(this[nombreVariable]);
    
   }
```

Here is a stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x5heks?file=src/app/app.component.ts